# Openpyxl for Python TypeError when conditionally formatting

Tags: python, typeerror, openpyxl

I have a Python script that uses Openpyxl to create a report, and it conditionally formats one of the columns. This script has worked successfully for a while. Now I am moving the script to a new computer, and with the new computer I have an updated version of Openpyxl, and the script no longer works (new computer is using Openpyxl 2.5.3, old one is using 2.4.1).

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.MultiCellRange'>
```

And here is the line it is tripping up on:

```
    ws.conditional_formatting.add('A3:B{0}'.format(report_query.oli_num_of_rows + 2,),
                              CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=['{0}'.format(two_days_old)], stopIfTrue=True, fill=yellow_fill))
```

I wish I had a better idea of what is causing this problem, but I honestly don't know where to start to look at it. What can I do to fix this problem?

Thanks for your help as always!

---

This is not a duplicate of a question asking how to conditional format in openpyxl because I'm not asking how to conditionally format. I have done that already in openpyxl 2.4.1 many times and it's worked fine. When I upgraded my script to openpyxl 2.5.3, the script started to return a TypeError on the conditionally format lines. What has changed from 2.4.1 to 2.5.3 to cause a TypeError when these conditionally format lines used to work, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply conditional formatting in openpyxl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307790/how-to-apply-conditional-formatting-in-openpyxl)

Comment: Hello! Where you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @FranciscoFiuza as of 3.1.2 error still exists. :(